# Conditional formatting comparing two adjacent columns for every other column

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

It's easy to do conditional formatting that compares 2 columns, e.g.: `=$A1=$B1`. But what if I ***also*** want to compare C and D, but ***NOT*** B and C? Ideally, I'd like to do this with a single conditional formatting formula since I have many columns, but I'll settle for VBA if necessary (I'm just unfamiliar with conditional formatting in VBA).

NOTE: I've tried some variations of `=AND(MOD(COLUMN(),2),A1=B1)`, but that hasn't worked.

NOTE 2: Here's some more specifics: Basically I'm comparing data in two nearly identical tables, and I want to highlight any differences. So for example, each table has a "Study_ID" column, and I want to view those side by side on a new sheet, e.g. in Columns A and B, highlighting unmatched cells in both columns. It would be easy to say `=$A1:$B1` and apply to `=$A$A:$B$B`. But I'm also viewing "Name" side by side, e.g. in Columns C and D. I *could* add a new formula `=$C1:$D1`. But since the source tables have like 20 columns, that would require like 20+ formulas. I'd prefer one.

Thanks!

The image below was accomplished using multiple formulas (`=$A1<>$B1`, applied to `=$A$1:$B$4`, and `=$C1<>$D1`, applied to `=$C$1:$D$4`)

[image: Solution with multiple formulas]

Comment: Sorry, not sure how else to answer this: "What do you want formatted" Adjacent cells. "What conditions": If the two cells are different. Then I want to do this for all adjacent columns, but only for every other column. So compare A and B, C and D, but NOT B and C

Comment: @pnuts is asking for you to please post an example of your data as is and how you would like it to look.  A photo is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Didn't realize further details were required. After 3 examples, I thought enough info had been provided.

Comment: No, I think you'll need new rules for each pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  Figured out a single formula that will do it:

```
=A2<>OFFSET(A2,,IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=1,1,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hm. That didn't seem to work for me. Intuitively, the formulas make sense: "If the column is odd/even and the two adjacent cells are not equal, then apply the formatting". However, this doesn't work for all of them. Using the picture that I posted above, Cells A3 and B3 are incorrectly highlighted, as are cells C2 and D2. To be clear, I replace `B1<>A1` with `B2<>A2` as the column headers, which are necessarily unique, are in row 1.

Comment: I did. I used `$D` instead of `$H` since that's where my data goes to. It seems to be comparing A2 to B2, C2 to D2, **and** B2 to C2, rather than just the first two.

Comment: Try setting the area with numbers like the picture.  I works for me.  Are you sure that there are no invisible characters, like spaces or line returns?  Sometime when importing data things like that are added.

Comment: Your picture doesn't have numbers. And yes I'm sure. I didn't import. I typed and copied and pasted, since I had to create fake data.

Comment: I edited it again, try hitting F5 to refresh to get latest.

Comment: Perfect! I'll take a sec to digest the formula, but it worked. Thanks again!